# Swipe To Delete TableView Row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have my array:

```
self.colorNames = [[NSArray alloc] 
initWithObjects:@"Red", @"Green",
@"Blue", @"Indigo", @"Violet", nil];
```

I've tried everything I can find, but there's always errors. I want to be able to swipe so that the delete button appears, and then press the delete button and have that row removed.

Full code (everything relating to the table):

```
// HEADER FILE
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

  IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
    NSMutableArray *colorNames;

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *colorNames;


@end

// IMPLEMENTATION

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize colorNames; 

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.colorNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] 
    initWithObjects:@"Red", @"Green",
    @"Blue", @"Indigo", @"Violet", nil];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    //[tableView setEditing:YES animated:NO];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
 }

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    int count = [colorNames count];
    return count;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}  

 // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
             reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 }
     // Configure the cell.
     cell.textLabel.text = [self.colorNames objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];

 return cell;

 }
```

Comment: You've only posted an `NSArray` here. Please post the relevant code for how you set up the `UITableView`.

Comment: It's there. Please offer any possible input you may have, as I appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You have to implement the necessary `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` methods.

**First, add this:**

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
```

**Then:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //remove the deleted object from your data source.
        //If your data source is an NSMutableArray, do this
        [self.dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView reloadData]; // tell table to refresh now
    }
}
```

Comment: I've gotten that far, however I need to know what to actually put in those methods. I've gotten this far a dozen times, but I always come to some kind of barrier due to outdated tutorials.

Comment: These methods haven't changed very much since iOS' inception. Outdated tutorials should work fine.

Comment: Seems like it's the right way to go. I'll check it out. Thank you for your help =)

Comment: Only if you're willing to help out just a little more, when I press delete I get SIGABRT that logs this: "[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a0fc20"

Comment: Use `NSMutableArray` instead of `NSArray`.

Comment: Figured it out! I forgot to change the NSArray in the implementation to match with the header file. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have a void method returning `YES`. Should it just return / do nothing?

Comment: @JamesWebster oops, nice catch. Fixed.

Comment: Aslo add [tableView reloadData]; just before the last bracket of the method.

Comment: @GerardGrundy is correct, should be like this: `if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
[self.toDoItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.tableView reloadData];
}`

Comment: [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]; is much better for Animation

Comment: Apple specifically says `[tableView reloadData]` "should not be called in the methods that insert or delete rows". Use @Beninho85's suggestion instead.

Answer (score 21):

For a start, your `colorNames` should be an NSMutableArray rather than an NSArray. You can’t add or remove objects from a regular (non-mutable) array; you’d have to recreate it each time you made a change. Switching that will make this easier. For your implementation of `-tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`, you’ll then be able to do something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [colorNames removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    }
}
```

Comment: The mutable array part helped, I don't know why I didn't catch it before!

Comment: +1 for the [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths] to make the UI update as well as the datasource

Answer (score 6):

Implement the following method:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

Comment: I added that already. What I need to do is actually allow deletion.

Comment: If you just want to delete, you don't appear to need to implement this method as the 'Delete' button is the default behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3 and Swift 4 answer without using reloadData**

I prefer using deleteRows instead of using reloadData.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Enables editing only for the selected table view, if you have multiple table views
    return tableView == yourTableView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Deleting new item in the table
        yourTableView.beginUpdates()
        yourDataArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        yourTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        yourTableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Comment: deleteRows already handles the tableView updates for you. You can omit begin/endUpdates.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete){
        Comment *comment = [self.commentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
            if([self.thePost deleteCommentForCommentId:comment.commentId]){
                if (indexPath.row < self.commentArray.count) {
                    [self.commentArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    [self.tvComments reloadData];
                });
            }
        });
    }
     [self.tvComments reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift Version:**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
         dataArray?.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
         tableview.reloadData()
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 Version :**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        // delete item at indexPath

    }
    return [delete]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add **UITableViewDelegate** and **UITableViewDataSource** methods.

You can add **multiple buttons** on UITableView Row Swipe:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        return YES;
    }

-(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
        UITableViewRowAction *delete = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Delete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
        {
            // Delete something here
        }];
        delete.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    
        UITableViewRowAction *more = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@" More " handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
        {
           //You function call:
        }];
        more.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.188 green:0.514 blue:0.984 alpha:1];
    
        return @[delete, more]; //array with all the buttons.
    }`
```