# Delete functionality similar to iOS delete messages

Tags: ios, ios5, imessage

I have a list of items in UITableView which I want to delete, is there a way to reuse similar delete functionality as of delete messages in iPhone?

Comment: There are a lot of questions like this already.

[see here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471642/swipe-to-delete-tableview-row

Comment: iphone delete messages functionality is not swipe to delete

Answer (score 4):

You will need to implement some of the UITableViewDelegate methods such as:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

To provide the default functionality for editing and deleting cells, you will need to include the edit button in the navigation bar, a la:

```
[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:[self editButtonItem]];
```

This should cater for most of the "default" implementation you're looking for, with some amendments to wrap around your code of course :)