# iOS - Swipe to delete while also allowing moving rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My table view is in editing mode allowing my cells to be moved around. Is it possible to also add swipe to delete, NOT using the red-circle-delete button.

I want to be able to show just the move cell image, allowing moving, and also have a swipe to delete.

Is this possible?

This is what I currently have going on.

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
    else
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 1)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible, though not as simple as you'd probably like. There are three parts to this:

1. The "swipe" gesture
2. The UI animation
3. The delete action

The "swipe" gesture should probably not be a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`. `UIPanGestureRecognizer` will update as the user moves their finger around and matches what the user expects.

The animation should have two parts: update and complete. Update should simply pan the cell view inside of the cell to follow along with the user's finger. Once the gesture has reached a point of "completion" then animate the cell view going off screen.

Lastly, the delete action should be familiar if you've used the `UITableViewDelegate` methods. If not, [here's a link to a helpful answer on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471642/swipe-to-delete-tableview-row).

I would actually implement these out of order. First, programmatically test deleting a row. When that works, add an `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to call the delete row. Then move the cell view around with the pan gesture. Finally, animate the completion of the cell view moving around.